# CakePHP 3.0 -> Between find condition

Tags: cakephp, orm, cakephp-3.0

Is it possible to do a "BETWEEN ? AND ?" where condition LIKE in cakephp 2.5?
In cakephp 2.5 I write something like

```
'conditions' => ['start_date BETWEEN ? AND ?' => ['2014-01-01', '2014-12-32']]
```

how can I migrate that?

additionally I would write something like

```
'conditions' => [ '? BETWEEN start_date AND end_date'] => '2014-03-31']
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

### Expressions

Between expression are supported out of the box, however they only support the first case without additional fiddling:

```
$Query = $Table
    ->find()
    ->where(function($exp) {
        return $exp->between('start_date', '2014-01-01', '2014-12-32', 'date');
    });
```

If you'd wanted to handle the second case via the between method, then you'd have to pass all values as expressions, which can easily go wrong, as they will not be subject to escaping/parameter binding in that case, you'd have to do that on your own (which is anything but recommended! See the security notes in [**the manual for `PDO::quote()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php)), something along the lines of:

```
use Cake\Database\Expression\IdentifierExpression;
use Cake\Database\Expression\QueryExpression;
use Cake\ORM\Query;

// ...

$Query = $Table
    ->find()
    ->where(function(QueryExpression $exp, Query $query) {
        return $exp->between(
            $query->newExpr(
                $query->connection()->driver()->quote(
                    '2014-03-31',
                    \PDO::PARAM_STR
                )
            ),
            new IdentifierExpression('start_date'),
            new IdentifierExpression('end_date')
        );
    });
```

That might feel a little inconvenient for such a basic SQL expression that is supported by all SQL dialects that CakePHP ships with, so you may have a reason here to use a raw SQL snippet with value bindig instead.

It should be noted however that expressions are often the better choice when it comes to for example cross dialect support, as they can be (more or less) easily transformed at compile time, see the implementations of `SqlDialectTrait::_expressionTranslators()`. Also expressions usually support automatic identifier quoting.

### Value binding

Via manual value binding you can pretty much create anything you like. It should however be noted that whenever possible, you should use expressions instead, as they are easier to port, which happens out of the box for quite a few expressions already.

```
$Query = $Table
    ->find()
    ->where([
        'start_date BETWEEN :start AND :end'
    ])
    ->bind(':start', '2014-01-01', 'date')
    ->bind(':end',   '2014-12-31', 'date');
```

That way the second case can also be solved very easily, like:

```
$Query = $Table
    ->find()
    ->where([
        ':date BETWEEN start_date AND end_date'
    ])
    ->bind(':date', '2014-03-31', 'date');
```

### A mixture of both (safest and most compatible approach)

It's also possible to mix both, ie use an expression that makes use of custom bindings, something along the lines of this:

```
use Cake\Database\Expression\IdentifierExpression;
use Cake\Database\Expression\QueryExpression;
use Cake\ORM\Query;

// ...

$Query = $Table
    ->find()
    ->where(function(QueryExpression $exp, Query $query) {
        return $exp->between(
            $query->newExpr(':date'),
            new IdentifierExpression('start_date'),
            new IdentifierExpression('end_date')
        );
    })
    ->bind(':date', '2014-03-31', 'date');
```

That way you could handle the second case using possibly portable expressions, and don't have to worry about quoting/escaping input data and identifiers manually.

### Regular comparison using array syntax

All that being said, in the end `BETWEEN` is just the same as using two separate simple conditions like this:

```
$Query = $Table
    ->find()
    ->where([
        'start_date >=' => '2014-01-01',
        'start_date <=' => '2014-12-32',
    ]);
```

```
$Query = $Table
    ->find()
    ->where([
        'start_date >=' => '2014-03-31',
        'end_date <=' => '2014-03-31',
    ]);
```

But don't be mad, if you read all the way down to here, at least you learned something about the ins and outs of the query builder.

### See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Advanced Conditions](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#advanced-conditions)**
- **[API > \Cake\Database\Query::bind()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/class-Cake.Database.Query.html#_bind)**

---

<del>Currently there seems to be only two options.</del> The core now supports this out of the box, the following is just kept for reference.

## Value binding (via the database query builder)

For now the ORM query builder (`Cake\ORM\Query`), the one that is being retrived when invoking for example `find()` on a table object, doesn't support value binding

**https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/4926**

So, for being able to use bindings you'd have to use the underlying database query builder (`Cake\Database\Query`), which can for example be retrived via [**`Connection::newQuery()`**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#Cake%5CDatabase%5CConnection%3A%3AnewQuery).

Here's an example:

```
$conn = ConnectionManager::get('default');

$Query = $conn->newQuery(); 
$Query
    ->select('*')
    ->from('table_name')
    ->where([
        'start_date BETWEEN :start AND :end'
    ])
    ->bind(':start', new \DateTime('2014-01-01'), 'date')
    ->bind(':end',   new \DateTime('2014-12-31'), 'date');

debug($Query->execute()->fetchAll());
```

This would result in a query similar to this

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    table_name
WHERE
    start_date BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-12-31'
```

---

## A custom expression class

Another option would be a custom [**expression**](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.Database.ExpressionInterface.html) class that generates appropriate SQL snippets. Here's an example.

Column names should be wrapped into identifier expression objects in order to them be auto quoted (in case auto quoting is enabled), the key > value array syntax is for binding values, where the array key is the actual value, and the array value is the datatype.

***Please note that it's not safe to directly pass user input for column names, as they are not being escaped! Use a whitelist or similar to make sure the column name is safe to use!***

### Field between values

```
use App\Database\Expression\BetweenComparison;
use Cake\Database\Expression\IdentifierExpression;

// ...

$between = new BetweenComparison(
    new IdentifierExpression('created'),
    ['2014-01-01' => 'date'],
    ['2014-12-31' => 'date']
);

$TableName = TableRegistry::get('TableName');
$Query = $TableName
    ->find()
    ->where($between);

debug($Query->execute()->fetchAll());
```

This would generate a query similar to the one above.

### Value between fields

```
use App\Database\Expression\BetweenComparison;
use Cake\Database\Expression\IdentifierExpression;

// ...

$between = new BetweenComparison(
    ['2014-03-31' => 'date'],
    new IdentifierExpression('start_date'),
    new IdentifierExpression('end_date')
);

$TableName = TableRegistry::get('TableName');
$Query = $TableName
    ->find()
    ->where($between);

debug($Query->execute()->fetchAll());
```

This on the other hand would result in a query similar to this

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    table_name
WHERE
    '2014-03-31' BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
```

#### The expression class

```
namespace App\Database\Expression;

use Cake\Database\ExpressionInterface;
use Cake\Database\ValueBinder;

class BetweenComparison implements ExpressionInterface {

    protected $_field;
    protected $_valueA;
    protected $_valueB;

    public function __construct($field, $valueA, $valueB) {
        $this->_field = $field;
        $this->_valueA = $valueA;
        $this->_valueB = $valueB;
    }

    public function sql(ValueBinder $generator) {
        $field  = $this->_compilePart($this->_field,  $generator);
        $valueA = $this->_compilePart($this->_valueA, $generator);
        $valueB = $this->_compilePart($this->_valueB, $generator);

        return sprintf('%s BETWEEN %s AND %s', $field, $valueA, $valueB);
    }

    public function traverse(callable $callable) {
        $this->_traversePart($this->_field,  $callable);
        $this->_traversePart($this->_valueA, $callable);
        $this->_traversePart($this->_valueB, $callable);
    }

    protected function _bindValue($value, $generator, $type) {
        $placeholder = $generator->placeholder('c');
        $generator->bind($placeholder, $value, $type);
        return $placeholder;
    }

    protected function _compilePart($value, $generator) {
        if ($value instanceof ExpressionInterface) {
            return $value->sql($generator);
        } else if(is_array($value)) {
            return $this->_bindValue(key($value), $generator, current($value));
        }
        return $value;
    }

    protected function _traversePart($value, callable $callable) {
        if ($value instanceof ExpressionInterface) {
            $callable($value);
            $value->traverse($callable);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I guess this isn't answer the question. The question is based on cakephp 2.5 so how to do something like this in cakephp 3: 'conditions' => ['start_date BETWEEN ? AND ?' => ['2014-01-01', '2014-12-32']]
because its important that its part of condition so that we can wrote it as well on paginate.
$this->Model->find('all', ['conditions' => $conditions])
or $this->paginate = ['conditions' => $conditions]

Comment: @JohnLaniba I have no idea what you're trying to say.

Comment: I mean I have a lot of code that look like this on pagination
$this->paginate = ['conditions' => $conditions]
$conditions is array and it works on cakephp 3 except the between conditions. So how to do something like this: 'conditions' => ['start_date BETWEEN ? AND ?' => ['2014-01-01', '2014-12-32']] on an array conditions

Comment: its weird but the answer below seems right.
so as simple as this 'conditions' => ['start_date BETWEEN "2014-01-01" AND "2014-12-32"']

Comment: @JohnLaniba The techniques shown in my answer are the ones you should use when dealing with user input (which must be considered unsafe), and/or when you need the expression to be transformable later on (for example for custom SQL dialects). If you'd had actually hardcoded string values, then building a simple SQL snippet string is a possible solution too. That being said, for complex conditions you can pass a closure to the `conditions` option, just like `where()` accepts it, or you can build the query yourself and pass it to the paginator (it accepts tables as well as query objects).

Comment: any example how to this on pagination? it would greatly appreciated. tnx

Comment: @JohnLaniba An example of what exactly?

Comment: nevermind.. I guess you're wrong that it isn't safe to use it because I can't see any difference using a normal query:
$conditions = ['start_date BETWEEN "'. $this->request->query['date_from'] . '" AND "'. $this->request->query['date_to'] . '"'];
$this->Model->find()->where($conditions);

Comment: @JohnLaniba No, I'm not wrong, please read about SQL injections, the snippet you're showing there is vulnerable to that! Try for example passing `2014-12-31" OR 1=1; --` for `date_to` (and that's just something rather harmless, imagine people slipping in `UNION`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` queries!

Comment: the variables is escape by default: mysql_escape_string() so how can you do that?
but i think you're right about it. maybe I need to find a better solution on how to use it on a pagination or a complex  query condition

Comment: @JohnLaniba Not only is `mysql_escape_string()` deprecated since PHP 4.3.0 (and luckily completely removed as of PHP 7), but CakePHP uses PDO, so I'm not sure what exactly you're referring to. There is no automatic request data escaping in CakePHP, maybe you're doing it manually, but using `mysql_escape_string()` surely isn't a good idea. If you wanted to escape things manually at all (which isn't a good idea in the first place), you'd use the current connections/drivers `quote()` method. Long story short, it's `{the_current_year}`, prepared statements are the way to go!!

Comment: Yay m8 thank you, this was very useful.
Another way to bind data for the function executed inside the ->where(function()) is registering them into the class properties. This way it can be used inside the function scope and without ->bind(), such like: 
`
//Controller
$this->_something = $something;
`
And now u can call the property $this->_something inside the where function scope

Answer (score 6):

You can use one of following 2 methods.

**Method 1 :**

```
$start_date = '2014-01-01 00:00:00';
$end_date = '2014-12-31 23:59:59';
$query = $this->Table->find('all')
         ->where(function ($exp, $q) use($start_date,$end_date) {
             return $exp->between('start_date', $start_date, $end_date);
         });
$result = $query->toArray();
```

**Method 2:**

```
$start_date = '2014-01-01 00:00:00';
$end_date = '2014-12-31 23:59:59';
$query = $this->Table->find('all')
         ->where([
            'start_date BETWEEN :start AND :end'
         ])
         ->bind(':start', new \DateTime($start_date), 'datetime')
         ->bind(':end',   new \DateTime($end_date), 'datetime');
$result = $query->toArray();
```

Answer (score -1):

**I'm using it like this**

```
$this->Table->find()->where(['data_inicio BETWEEN '.'\''.$data_inicio.'\''.' AND .'\''.$data_final.'\''.' ']);
```

Answer (score -4):

Hello guys please use this query to get data on the basis of range of value

```
    $query = $this->Leads->find('all', 
array('conditions'=>array('postcode BETWEEN '.$postcodeFrom.' and'.$postcodeTo.''), 'recursive'=>-1));
                  debug($query);
                  print_r($query->toArray());
```

Comment: No, please, everyone _**DO NOT use this**_! This is an SQL injection vulnerability - you should _never ever_ trust user data and include it directly into queries, which is effectively what this example is doing, as single value entries in conditions, just like left hand side values of `key => value` entries, are not subject of binding, instead these string will be inserted into the query as is!