# Between condition in cakephp 3 beta

Tags: model, between, cakephp-3.0

What is the equivalent of this code in cakephp 3

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name BETWEEN value1 AND value2;
```

I try this

```
$condition["Advertisements.created BETWEEN ? AND ?"] = [1418874212 , 1418889212];
```

But it does not work

Comment: possible duplicate of [CakePHP 3.0 -> Between find condition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26430259/cakephp-3-0-between-find-condition)

Answer (score 0):

```
            $Query = $Table
            ->find('all')
            ->where([
                'date BETWEEN :start_date AND :end_date'   
            ])

            ->bind(':start_date ',$s_date)
            ->bind(':end_date',$e_days); 

            $Query->hydrate(false);
            $result = $Query->toArray();
```

Comment: Could you please provide a brief description.

Comment: Like if You want to find all the dates between two dates that are start_date and end_date, then yore condition should be like this :'conditions' => ['date BETWEEN start_date AND end_date' => ['2015-10-07', '2015-10-20']] ..... after that bind() method can be use to bind data because it's not safe to directly pass user input for column names..

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of following 2 methods.

**Method 1 :**

```
$start_date = '2015-11-01 00:00:00';
$end_date = '2015-11-01 23:59:59';
$query = $this->Advertisements->find('all')
         ->where(function ($exp, $q) use($start_date,$end_date) {
             return $exp->between('created', $start_date, $end_date);
         });
$result = $query->toArray();
```

**Method 2:**

```
$start_date = '2015-11-01 00:00:00';
$end_date = '2015-11-01 23:59:59';
$query = $this->Advertisements->find('all')
         ->where([
            'created BETWEEN :start AND :end'
         ])
         ->bind(':start', new \DateTime($start_date), 'datetime')
         ->bind(':end',   new \DateTime($end_date), 'datetime');
$result = $query->toArray();
```