# CakePHP 3: Error while passing an array in URL

Tags: php, cakephp, url-rewriting, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to pass `datetime` variables into my `exportcsv` method to generate `.csv` file with data from indicated time period.

Both variables are associative arrays that look like this:

```
[
 'beginning' => [
    'year' => '2016',
    'month' => '06',
    'day' => '23',
    'hour' => '11',
    'minute' => '15'
  ],
  'end' => [
    'year' => '2016',
    'month' => '06',
    'day' => '29',
    'hour' => '11',
    'minute' => '15'
   ]
]
```

When I try to pass variables I get an error with this message (yep, I've got the same two warnings):

```
Warning (2): rawurlencode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given [CORE\src\Routing\Route\Route.php, line 574]

Warning (2): rawurlencode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given [CORE\src\Routing\Route\Route.php, line 574]
```

`rawurlencode()` is a basic PHP function and this is the `line 574`:

`$pass = implode('/', array_map('rawurlencode', $pass));`

It looks like some problem with URL rewriting, but frankly I don't know how to fix it. Any ideas?

**`exportcsv` method in `EventsController`**

```
public function exportcsv($beginning = null, $end = null)
{
 if ($this->request->is('post')) {
  $beginning = $this->request->data['Export']['beginning']; 
  $end = $this->request->data['Export']['end'];              

  return $this->redirect([$beginning, $end]);
 }

 if (!$beginning && !$end) {
  return $this->render();
 }

 $this->response->download('export.csv');
$data = $this->Events->find('all')
                          ->select([
                            'title',
                            'created',
                            'description',
                            'ended',
                            'working_hours',
                            'price',
                            'username' => 'Users.name',
                            'statusname' => 'Statuses.name',
                            'employeename' => 'Employees.name'
                          ])
                          ->leftJoinWith('Statuses')
                          ->leftJoinWith('Users')
                          ->leftJoinWith('Employees')
                          ->where(["created BETWEEN " . $beginning . " AND " . $end])
                          ->autoFields(true)
                          ->toArray();
$_serialize = 'data';
$_delimiter = chr(9); //tab
$_extract = ['title', 'created', 'description', 'ended', 'working_hours', 'price', 'username', 'statusname', 'employeename'];
$this->set(compact('data', '_serialize','_delimiter', '_extract'));
$this->viewBuilder()->className('CsvView.Csv');
return;
}
```

**`exportcsv.ctp` view:**

```
<div class="events form large-6 medium-4 columns content">
  <?= $this->Form->create('Export'); ?>
  <?= $this->Form->input('beginning', array('type'=>'datetime', 'interval' => 15, 'label' => 'Beginning:')); ?>
  <?= $this->Form->input('end', array('type'=>'datetime',  'interval' => 15, 'label' => 'End:')); ?>
  <?= $this->Form->button(__('Add')) ?>
  <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
</div>
```

Comment: where is `rawurlencode()` or `line 574`?

Comment: It looks like `rawurlencode()` is a basic PHP function. This is the aforementioned line: `$pass = implode('/', array_map('rawurlencode', $pass));`

Comment: why don't you include this line in your code? update your question with this code

Comment: So you've noticed that you can't pass arrays... how about trying to pass strings instead, ie build proper datetime strings from your separate values!?

Side note: Your `where()` conditions are prone to SQL injections! You'd better use expressions or proper manual bindings! **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26430259/cakephp-3-0-between-find-condition**

Comment: @ndm Thank you very much for your reply. I was hoping that there is another way to resolve this problem, but this also works. Also, thank you for reminding me of security issues, it's very important. Please add this comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass arrays in a URL array, the router doesn't support that. Also you need to additionally pass  Instead, convert your single values to proper datetime strings, you could easily do that via the `DateTimeType` class, something like

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    $beginning = $this->request->data('Export.beginning');
    $end = $this->request->data('Export.end');

    $type = \Cake\Database\Type::build('datetime');
    $beginning = $type->marshal($beginning)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $end = $type->marshal($end)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    return $this->redirect([
        $beginning,
        $end
    ]);
}
```

Also, as already mentioned in the comments, you need to fix your `where()` call, as currently it has an SQL injection vulnerability. The keys of `key => value` items, as well as value only items, are not going to be bound, but inserted into the query directly!

Cakes expression builder ships with methods to safely generate `BETWEEN` expressions:

```
->where(function(\Cake\Database\Expression\QueryExpression $exp) use ($beginning, $end) {
    return $exp->between('Events.created', $beginning, $end);
});
```

See also

- **[API > \Cake\Database\DateTimeType::marshal()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/class-Cake.Database.Type.DateTimeType.html#_marshal)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Advanced Conditions](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#advanced-conditions)**
- **[CakePHP 3.0 -> Between find condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26430259/cakephp-3-0-between-find-condition)**

Answer (score 0):

your redirect is wrong

```
return $this->redirect([
    'controller' => 'yourController', 
    'action' => 'yourAction', 
    $yourData]
);
```

see the [Cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers.html#redirecting-to-other-pages) for more information on this topic

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried to change my redirect to something like this: `return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'Events', 'action' => 'exportcsv', $beginning, $end]);` but it gives the same error and when I tried this: `return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'Events', 'action' => 'exportcsv', [$beginning, $end]]);` nothing happens. It didn't start to download the file and just reload the page so I assume that values are not assigned to `$beginning` and `$end`.