# Between clause for cakephp 3

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp-3.0, query-builder, between

```
select * from user where HOUR(NOW()) BETWEEN earliest_login AND latest_login
```

`earliest_login`, `latest_login` are two columns .

Please let me know how I can write this in cakephp3

code I have tried is:

```
$query->where(
    [
        function($exp) {
            return $exp->between('HOUR(NOW())', 'earliest_login', 'latest_login');
        }
```

it is not working .

Please let me know if anyone has a solution.

Comment: Do you get an error?

Comment: yes the query is not executing properly in query object params type for earliest_login and latest_login is null

Comment: duplicat question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26430259/cakephp-3-0-between-find-condition

Comment: You need to use expressions for the arguments passed to `between()`, or use value binding instead. I've updated the code examples in the duplicated questions answer mentioned by @YosiAzwan

Answer (score 2):

The field names are used in expressions, and SQL snippets should never contain untrusted content.

**You can use :**

```
$query = $users->find()
->where(function ($exp, $q) {
    return $exp->between('Users.created', date1, date2);
})
```

this will create sql like something similar:

```
select * from users  WHERE created BETWEEN '$date1' AND '$date2'
```

**You can also use gt() and lt() in in query**

```
$query = $articles->find()
    ->where(function ($exp) {
   return $exp
        ->gt('created', '2016-07-05 12:02:15')
        ->lt('created', '2016-07-10 12:02:15');
});
```

**and if want differece between two dates**

```
$query = $this->Users->find();

$diff= $query->func()->dateDiff(['2016-07-04 12:02:15', '2016-07-07 18:29:57']);

$query->select(['difference' => $diff,]);
```

For more inforamation please read this link
http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html

Comment: Your examples are solving different cases than the one the OP is showing.