# How to get data type date from database?

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I have table Birthdays.
Birthdays fields: id | user_id | birthday (type date: y-m-d)
Data from url $_GET['date'] is '1991-09-10'
In BirthdaysController i have a query

```
$arrayDate = $this->Birthday->find()->where(['birthday' => $_GET['date'] ])->all();
```

but i want to find by format '1991-09'.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Please help me!

Comment: It's a little hard to tell what exactly you are asking for, please try to be more specific about the actual technical problem that you are facing. ps, do not use superglobals in CakePHP directly, use the corresponding access methods of **[the request object](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#query-string-parameters)**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess what you want to do is to find people with a birthday date for the month of the year given?

First of all, you should use the GET parameters like this `$this->request->query('date');` and not like this `$_GET['date']`.

You'll have to use the between function, so to be sure you're using the first and last day of the month, convert the date like this :

```
$startDate = $endDate = new \DateTime($this->request->query('date'));
$startDate->modify('first day of this month');
$endDate->modify('last day of this month');
```

And then you just have to create a query like this

```
$arrayDate = $this->Birthday
    ->find()
    ->where(function($exp) {
        return $exp->between('birthday', $startDate->format('Y-m-d'), $endDate->format('Y-m-d'), 'date');
    });
```

They're other ways to use this between find conditions, you should read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26430259/cakephp-3-0-between-find-condition).