# mysql between statement in cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I am trying to retrieve the row from table allowances where the current date is present between the two fields date_from  and date_to .
here is the sql query :

```
SELECT * FROM `allowances` WHERE desg_id=4  AND CURDATE() between date_from and date_to
```

now how to write this query in cakephp2 find . I am trying this :

```
$allowance = $this->  Allowance->find('all',array(
'conditions'=>array(
'? BETWEEN ? AND ?'=>array( date('Y-m-d'), 'Allowance.date_from', 'Allowance.date_to')
)));
```

I got the sql output :

```
SELECT `Allowance`.`id`, `Allowance`.`date_from`, `Allowance`.`date_to`, FROM `db_demo`.`allowances` WHERE '2017-03-16' BETWEEN 'Allowance.date_from' AND 'Allowance.date_to'
```

here is the problem with quotes.
Unfortunately its not working.whats the wrong with this query.

Comment: what is your `date_from` and `date_to` field type `datetime` or `date` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26430259/cakephp-3-0-between-find-condition

Comment: field type date

Comment: Please always mention your exact CakePHP version! While this looks like 2.x, it's not 100% clear. Also please note that "_doesn't work_" is not a proper problem description! Even if the problem might be obvious for people that know the CakePHP internals, please always be as specific as possible as to what _exactly_ happens, and what you'd expect to happen instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way:

```
$this->Order->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'id' => $id,
        'created >=' => $start_date,
        'created <=' => $end_date . ' 23:59:59',
        'my_field LIKE' => '%whatever%'
));
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot bind identifiers that way, as bound strings end up as string literals, as can be seen in the generated query. Either add the identifiers in the SQL snippet on the left hand side of the condition:

```
'? BETWEEN Allowance.date_from AND Allowance.date_to' => date('Y-m-d')
```

or use expressions (which isn't really worth the hassle though):

```
$dataSource = $this->Allowance->getDataSource();

// ...

'? BETWEEN ? AND ?' => array(
    date('Y-m-d'),
    // note that using expressions is unsafe for user input!
    $dataSource->expression('Allowance.date_from'),
    $dataSource->expression('Allowance.date_to')
)
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Models > Retrieving Your Data > Complex Find Conditions](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#complex-find-conditions)**