# Between query in cakephp 3.3

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

**THE QUERY IS WORKING**

Want to write the query below by using cakephp 3.3

```
SELECT
```

Books.id AS `Books__id`, 
  Books.title AS `Books__title`, 
  Books.for_min_age AS `Books__for_min_age`, 
  Books.for_max_age AS `Books__for_max_age`, 
  Books.for_min_grade AS `Books__for_min_grade`, 
  Books.for_max_grade AS `Books__for_max_grade`
FROM 
  books Books 
WHERE 
    4 BETWEEN Books.for_min_age AND Books.for_max_age
    OR
    2 BETWEEN Books.for_min_grade AND Books.for_max_grade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieve this by -

```
 $this->find()->where([$age . ' BETWEEN Books.for_min_age AND Books.for_max_age OR ' . $grade . ' BETWEEN Books.for_min_grade AND Books.for_max_grade']);
```

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you even tried to find the answer. If that was the case you would have found out that `BETWEEN` won’t work the way you described here. Afaik.

The following code works in CakePHP assuming your Models are set up correctly.

```
$age = 4;
$grade = 2;

$query = TableRegistry::get('Books')->find('all')
    ->select([
        'id', 
        'title',
        'for_min_age',
        'for_max_age',
        'for_min_grade',
        'for_max_grade'
    ]);

$query->where(function ($exp) use ($age, $grade) {
    $ageExp = $exp->and_(function ($and) use ($age) {
        return $and
            ->lte('for_min_age', $age)
            ->gte('for_max_age', $age);
    });

    $gradeExp = $exp->and_(function ($and) use ($grade) {
        return $and
            ->lte('for_min_grade', $grade)
            ->gte('for_max_grade', $grade);
    });

    return $exp->add(['OR' => [$ageExp, $gradeExp]]);
});

$data = $query->execute();
```

Which will result in:

```
SELECT 
  Books.id AS `Books__id`, 
  Books.title AS `Books__title`, 
  Books. for_min_age AS `Books__for_min_age`,
  Books. for_max_age AS `Books__for_max_age`,
  Books. for_min_grade AS `Books__for_min_grade`,
  Books. for_max_grade AS `Books__for_max_grade` 
FROM 
  books Books 
WHERE 
  (
    (
      for_min_age <= 4 
      AND for_max_age >= 4
    ) 
    OR (
      for_min_grade <= 2 
      AND for_max_grade >= 2
    )
  )
```

**EDIT**

You could theoretically do it this way, but CakePHP will cast `number` and `number2` as string, which will not work.

```
$query->where(function ($exp) use ($age, $grade) {
    return $exp->or_(function ($or) use ($age) {
        return $or->between($age, 'for_min_age', 'for_max_age');
    })->between($grade, 'for_min_grade', 'for_max_grade');
});
```

Comment: This is what you asked for and way over what you deserve.

Comment: the query is working you can try. I am looking  for $value BETWEEN column1 AND coulmn2

Comment: I updated the answer. It is not directly possible. But since `BETWEEN` is just a shorthand for the query I posted, you are good to go. Take it or leave it. See here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between

Comment: Additional note, expressing the `value BETWEEN column1 AND column2` syntax is actually possible, if one (for whatever reason) really wants to pursue that path instead of breaking things down to simple `AND` comparisons: **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26430259/cakephp-3-0-between-find-condition/26463384#26463384**