# build query in array for cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp, query-builder, cakephp-3.4

I am writing an application with search functionalities. There are many filters to be applied so I want to build the filter query outside the `find()` function in `CakePHP 3.4` Application

This is what I want to achieve

```
$start_year = $this->request->getQuery('start_year');
$end_year = $this->request->getQuery('end_year');
$keyword = $this->request->getQuery('keyword');
$make = $this->request->getQuery('make');

$query_builder = [];

if (!empty($keyword)) {
    $query_builder['keyword'] = $keyword;
}
if (!empty($make)) {
    $query_builder['make'] = $make;
}

if (!empty($start_year) && empty($end_year))
{
    $query_builder['year >'] = $start_year;
}

if (empty($start_year) && !empty($end_year)) {
    $query_builder['year <'] = $end_year;
}

if (!empty($start_year) && !empty($end_year)) {
    // how to written in BETWEEN query here on year column
}

$results = $this->Model->find()
    ->where($query_builder);
```

**How to build query in array for `IN BETWEEN` query ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (!empty($start_year) && !empty($end_year)) {
    $query_builder['year >='] = $start_year;
    $query_builder['year <='] = $end_year;
}
```

Comment: The second example will not work, [**binding values**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26430259/cakephp-3-0-between-find-condition) doesn't work like that anymore in CakePHP 3.x!