# CakePHP 3 quoting function names defined in 'fields' configuration of my find() call

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am querying a database table conveniently named `order` and because of that I had to set `'quoteIdentifiers' => true` in my app.php configuration. However, when I'm putting function names into the `fields` configuration of my `find()` call, CakePHP quotes them too.

```
    $orders->find('all', array(
        'fields' => array(
            'DATE(Orders.date_added)',
            'COUNT(*)',
        ),
        'conditions' => array(
            'Orders.order_status_id <>' => 0,
        ),
        'group' => array(
            'DATE(Orders.date_added)',
        ),
    ));
```

The query above ends up calling

```
SELECT <...>, `DATE(Orders.date_added)` FROM `order` <...>
```

which obviously throws an error.

I googled a lot, tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26430259/cakephp-3-0-between-find-condition):

```
    $orders = $orders->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'Orders.order_status_id <>' => 0,
        ),
        'group' => array(
            'DATE(Orders.date_added)',
        ),
    ))->select(function($exp) {
        return $exp->count('*');
    });
```

and that didn't work either, throwing me some array_combine error.

Is there any way for me to un-quote those function names, while keeping the rest of the query quoted automatically? Here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
SELECT <...>, DATE(Orders.date_added) FROM `order` <...>
```

Please help.

Comment: Use function expressions **https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#using-sql-functions**.

Comment: @ndm it worked. If you post this as an answer I'll gladly accept and upvote. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use function expressions, they will not be quoted, except for arguments that are explicitly being defined as identifiers:

```
$query = $orders->find();

$query
    ->select([
        'date' => $query->func()->DATE([
            'Orders.date_added' => 'identifier'
        ]),
        'count' => $query->func()->count('*')
    ])
    ->where([
        'Orders.order_status_id <>' => 0
    ])
    ->group([
        $query->func()->DATE([
            'Orders.date_added' => 'identifier'
        ])
    ]);
```

I'd generally suggest that you use expressions instead of passing raw SQL snippets wherever possible, it makes generating SQL more flexible, and more cross-schema compatible.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Using SQL Functions](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#using-sql-functions)**