# How to get values between two given values in Cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I want to get product with specified price range supplied using the below query but getting following error:

> Cannot convert value to string InvalidArgumentException

```
$product_List=$this->Products->find('all',array('conditions' => array('product_price BETWEEN ? and ?' => array($min, $max))));
```

Here product_price is of type varchar(100). Please help to sort out my issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CakePHP 3.0 -> Between find condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26430259/cakephp-3-0-between-find-condition)

Comment: @GregSchmidt:My question is about the error i am getting when using between, Cannot convert value to string InvalidArgumentException.

Comment: Did you read the linked question? They were using *exactly* the same "between ? and ?" format, which is not supported in CakePHP 3, and the answers tell them how to fix it.

Comment: You are getting the error because Cake is basically trying to make a query by directly appending the value part of your condition to the key part (`array('k' => 'v')` is converted to `k = "v"`), but your value part is an array, which it "cannot convert to string".

Comment: Thanks Greg Schmidt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's help you

```
$product_List = $this->Products->find('all')
                ->where(function ($exp) use($min,$max) {
                    return $exp->between('product_price', $min, $max); //Consider $min=100 ; $max =1000; product_price BETWEEN 100 AND 1000;
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way.

```
$product_List = $this->Products->find('all')
            ->where(['product_price <=' => $max, 'product_price >=' => $min]);
```