# How use between cakephp

Tags: mysql, cakephp, query-builder, between, cakephp-3.x

it does not return any error but neither any row but if there are fields but it does not collect them, which may be failing the query

```php
$tarea = $this->Signs
    ->find('all', [
        'conditions'=> array(
            'date_inicio BETWEEN "' . 
                $horaInicio->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') .
                '" and "' .
                $horaFin->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') .
                '"'
        )
    ])
    ->where([
        'user_id' => $horario->user_id,
        'date_fin IS NOT' => null
    ]);
```

This works if I remove the condition between, but if I put it it doesn't give an error but it doesn't return anything.

Comment: Please always mention your exact CakePHP version (last line in `lib/Cake/VERSION.txt` or `vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt`) - thanks!

Comment: Also if you have query problems, please always show the generated SQL! For proper `BETWEEN` expression generation, see for example **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26430259/cakephp-3-0-between-find-condition**.

Comment: But are there data records that fit the query? What is the start and end date and what does your database look like (extract)